# Unexplained change of date in Windows 10

Tags: windows

In my environment we are using Windows 10 Pro version for analytical applications. Sometimes unexplainedly time and date was going to back date.

We have changed the cmos battery, but after half a week of the analysis the date and time got changed again.

This type of issue may lead to data integrity issues.

Any suggestion on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be, that Windows 10 updates the time and does not know where it is. It may then apply a different time zone.

I would turn off automatic date changes in the settings first and then see if this is the issue.

There is software that synchronizes the time with an atomic clock. This would probably be better if you rely on the time and have an internet connection available.